# explode string by last occurence of string in string return first and last part

Tags: php

Update: The $string can have one ore more ";". I have to look after the last one.

```
$string = "Hello world; This is a nice day; after";

$out[] = trim( substr( strrchr ($string, ";"), 1 ) );
$out[] = trim( substr( strrchr ($string, ";"), 0 ) );

var_dump($out);
```

result:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "after"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "; after"
}

**but what I need is:**

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "after"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Hello world; This is a nice day"
}

How should I do it?

Comment: And what about playing with `explode()` instead?

Comment: Tried explode() but the string can varry, there is at least one ";" but there can be more. I have to look after last ";" and can only explode there. @fedorqui you show me how to play?

Comment: so do explode(";",$out) and explode(" ",$out)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dlm = "; ";
$string = "Hello world; This is a nice day; after";

$split = explode($dlm,$string);
$last = array_pop($split);
$out = array($last,implode($dlm,$split));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
string = "Hello world; This is a nice day; after";
$out[] = trim(substr(strrchr($string, ";"), 1));
$out[] = trim(substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ";")+1));
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/115197)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
$string = "Hello world; This is a nice day; after";
$parts  = explode(';', $string);
$output = array(trim(array_pop($parts)), implode(';', $parts));

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'after' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Hello world; This is a nice day' (length=31)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Hello world; This is a nice day; after";
$offset = strrpos($string,';');

$out[] = substr($string, $offset+1);
$out[] = trim(substr($string, 0, $offset));
print_r($out);
```

Comment: same as mine.but you are faster than me to post it.So i am deleting mine.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$string = "Hello world; This is a nice day; after";
/// Explode it
$exploded_string = explode(";", $string);
/// Get last element
$result['last_one'] = end($exploded_string);
/// Remove last element
array_pop($exploded_string);
/// Implode other ones
$result['previous_ones'] = implode(";", $exploded_string);

print_r($result);
```

Result will be:

```
Array ( [last_one] => after [previous_ones] => Hello world; This is a nice day )
```